# how to open help file in executable jar

Tags: java, executable-jar, chm

I want to open .chm help file when click on Help button. When i do it in eclipse its working good. but when i create executable jar file then its giving error that "can not open file".
this is my code:

```
String path = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getClass().getResource("/resources/UserAccountHelpNew.chm").getPath();

    String path1 = path.substring(1);
    System.out.println(path1);

    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("hh.exe "+path1);
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hh.exe can't open files in a jar.  You need to either write some code copy the contents of `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getClass().getResource("/resources/UserAcountHelpNew.chm")` to a place on the file system, or distribute this file alongside the executable jar.

The reason it works in Eclipse is because you probably have the file on the file system.  When your working directory changes, hh.exe can no longer find the file.

Comment: @Vinay Check the output of `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getClass().getResource("/resources/UserAccountHelpNew.chm").getPath()` (e.g. do `System.out.println(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getClass().getResource("/resources/UserAccountHelpNew.chm").getPath())`).  Notice that the path you get doesn't point to a file on your hard drive.

Comment: yeah i got it. but then what should i do? how can i open it?

Comment: @Vinay Instead of including UserAccountHelpNew.chm in the jar and doing `getResource`, you should put UserAccountHelpNew.chm outside the jar but in the same directory.  Then you can just do `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("hh.exe UserAccountHelpNew.chm").waitFor();`