# Display CHM file in JavaFX app

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, chm, javafx-webengine

Is there a way to display Compiled Help manual **CHM** in a **javaFX** app, without using `java.awt.Desktop` from **AWT**  ?

Calling A **CHM reader** using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(help.chm)` is an option, but to make it cross platform, this would require every user in **mac**, **win** and **linux** to have a CHM reader installed.

What's the best option for a cross platform solution ? should I extract it to **HTML** and display it in `javafx.scene.web.WebView` ?

Comment: Duplicate: [Call a help file in java application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37069113/call-a-help-file-in-java-application)

Comment: The thread mentioned shows how to call chm file inside a java app, not inside a javafx app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your wish to be platform independent, I'd advise to go to the HTML route as you yourself suggested. I don't know your reason for converting CHM to HTML if you also control the source, in that case I'd either use HTML directly or markdown to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
You should try this. It's works for me!

Comment: Please don't post images of code, It can't be cut/paste, it can't be searched and it can't be read with a screenreader. Also, in case the code you posted isn't your own, you should provide attribution to the work that the code has come from.